# Dailymotion API fulltext search : exclude keywords

Tags: dailymotion-api

Is there a way to search videos and exclude a list of keywords?

I tried to exclude terms through the API by passing the search `foo -bar` :

`https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?search=foo+-bar`

But the response contains video that matches both **foo** and **bar**.

The behaviour seems to be the same on the website's main search bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no, unfortunately Dailymotion doesn't offer a way to search for videos by exclude a list of keywords, -bar won't work on the API nor on the webbsite. 
What you can do though is to filter reponses on your side after you get them through the api.